# OpenGL - Problems getting even simple rendering to work with shaders

Tags: opengl, shader

I am trying to get my very simple shader working with my current OpenGL set up. I am using a shader manager and upon loading the shaders, all the output says they have loaded correctly.

Here is my data:

```
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};
```

Here is where i set up my buffer:

```
// This will identify our vertex buffer
GLuint vertexbuffer;

// Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

// The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

// Give our vertices to OpenGL.
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Here is my declaration of my shader using a tested and working shader loader:

```
Shader shader;
shader.loadFromFile(VERTEX_SHADER, resourcePath() + "tri.vert");
shader.loadFromFile(FRAGMENT_SHADER, resourcePath() + "tri.frag");
shader.createAndLinkProgram();
shader.use();
shader.addAttribute("position");
shader.unUse();
```

The attributes for this shader are then stored in a map. This is the rendering call:

shader.use();

```
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader["position"]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                          shader["position"], // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
                          3,                  // size
                          GL_FLOAT,           // type
                          GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                          0,                  // stride
                          (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                          );

    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader["position"]);

    shader.unUse();
```

I then swap the buffers. I tried with an old GL_TRIANGLES fixed pipeline drawing and it worked fine.

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
gl_Position.xyz = position;
}
```

Here is my fragment shader:

```
out vec3 color;

main()
{
color = vec3(1,0,0);
}
```

It is supposed to simply draw a red triangle. When I draw using intermediate mode, it renders fine. I am running Xcode on Mac OSX 10.7.4.

Comment: What is "intermediate mode"? If you're talking about Immediate mode (`glBegin/glEnd`), do you also mean using fixed-function T&L, or with this shader?

Comment: By fixed function I just assumed that the programmable shaders are considered the programmable pipeline and glBegin and glEnd are the old outdated fixed pipeline functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> gl_Position.xyz = position;

And what is the W coordinate? It's kind of important not to leave it undefined. If you want it to be 1.0, you need to set it to be that:

```
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick but it was still good to know. I am using shaders to try and render this. By intermediate mode, I just mean I used it for a quick second to see if my context and camera was set up correctly. It was. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think the problem is in the attribute function. I will work on this. Thank you Nicol. I always love seeing you show up when I have an OpenGL question. Do you work with OpenGL for a living?

Answer (score 0):

gl_Position must be provided with x,y,z,w coordinate.
In GLSL version above 1.50 u have to provide the matrix manipulation in the shader i.e u have to do ll the projection , model, view matrix using some math library like GLM http://glm.g-truc.net/

from the vertex data set the z coordinate is 0.0 which is co insiding with the center of the scene.prove some -ve value o the Z coordinate and check for the results.